# Ajax Request Only Returns Error But The Status Code Is 200 OK

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here I have a form with a Javascript file that grabs the inputs and sends it to the slim PHP page using jQuery's AJAX method when a button is clicked. The PHP simply prints `"Hello and welcome person_name"`, assuming that name is set and this is exactly what I want. I want to display that text in a div element on same page if the request is successful or an `alert` if it fails. But if it is error, I display the text `"Error"` in the div element.

Now when I test this I only see the text `"Error"` printed in the div. I inspected the page and saw the status is 200 0k, response is `"Hello and welcome my_name`, and other details...

[image]

```html
<form class="myform">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="a" id="x" required></input>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="a" id="y" required></input>
</form>
<button class="b" id="n">Submit</button>

<div id="display"></div>
<p></p>
```

```js
$("button#n").click(function() {
  $("p").html("YOU ARE HERE 1");

  var $username = $('input#x').val();
  var $password = $('input#y').val();
  var $mydata = $('.myform').serialize();

  if ($username != "" && $password != "") {
    $.ajax({
      data: $mydata,
      dataType: 'text',
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost/products/s11.php',
      success: function(responseText) {
        $('#display').html(responseText);
      },
      failure: function() {
        alert("Failed");
      },
      error: function() {
        $('#display').html("Error");
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

```php
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    print "Hello and welcome" . " " . $_POST['username'];
  } else { ?> 
    //do something else...
```

Comment: If the response is 200 OK but the `error` handler is hit, then it usually means that there's a formatting problem with the response. Try adding the correct parameters to the `error` handler function which enable you to get the error description to diagnose

Comment: Try using `echo "Hello and welcome" . " " . $_POST['username'];` instead of `print`.

Comment: use `echo` instead of `print`

Comment: Munna is right. Try the echo not the print

Comment: If the response is being sent - as you can see in the console, then it would seem the use of `print` isn't the issue. Although I agree `echo` would be better practice.

Comment: I suspect `dataType: 'text'` might be the problem – not sure how strict jQuery actually is about this, but unless you explicitly make it do something different, PHP responds with a `Content-Type: text/html` header by default.

Comment: Agreeing with you @CBroe

Comment: Thanks so much, but I just used echo as you suggested and it's still the same thing

Comment: I deleted the line datatType: 'text' and nothing changed, and I used dataType: 'text/html' still no changes

Comment: try `print_r($_POST)` on your page where you are running your php code and add a parameter in error function of your ajax request and then print it

Comment: Did you enclose end brac `}` in your php ?

Comment: @smacaz Why you used `var $username` instead of `var username` ?

Comment: I have removed the $ from all variables still no changes, and I have also used print_r($_POST...)  still no changes. I'm still in wonder.

Comment: I try it in my side. See the code i paste here https://pastebin.com/jmEeN7Sv and see the result https://ibb.co/bGmqc5. Just want to sure, did you enclose your end brac `}` in your php ?

Comment: Yes I did,  I inserted the closing brace.

Comment: Yes I did,  I inserted the closing brace.

Comment: I used your script but what I get back is the raw php script inside the div#display.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ataur Rahman Munna for all your assistance. It seems this problem is from my own machine since it worked on yours. Thank you everyone who have contributed in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

**I put the following first at the top of my php file and my problem was solved**

```html
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 100000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
```